# Navigate form fields and edit text with the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a script in a form of a web site, where pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key or the right arrow changes focus to the next field, or by pressing the Left arrow changes focus to the previous field.

I need to be able to use the arrow keys to change the cursor position while editing the text, without change the field focus and only go to the next field when the cursor is at the beginning or end of the text.

How I can make this?

The script code is as follows:

```
function tabulacion_manual(e,adelante,atras,saltar){
    if(saltar==1)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(adelante).focus();
            $(adelante).select();
        },150);
    }else{
        //tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        tecla = (window.event) ? window.event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
            
        switch(tecla){
            case 37: //atras
                $(atras).focus();
                break;
            case 38: //arriba
                $(atras).focus();
                break;
            case 40: //abajo
                $(adelante).focus();
                break;
            case 39: //derecha
                $(adelante).focus();
                break;
            case 13: //enter
                $(adelante).focus();
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The html code is:

```
<s:textfield name="programaFaena.fecha"  maxlength="10" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return tabulacion_manual(event,this,next())" autocomplete="off" readonly="false" >
```

Comment: What is your question?  What's not working?

Comment: also can you provide a piece of html code as well ?

Comment: So is your question "When processing a key event, how do I tell if the cursor is at the beginning or end of a text field?" (I'd suggest you avoid this type of functionality: users expect to use tab and shift-tab to move between fields - except of course Opera users, who get a different set of keyboard controls - but either way users expect keyboard navigation to be consistent within their chosen browser.)

Comment: I need to be able to use the arrow keys to change the cursor position while editing the text, without change the field focus and i dont know how i do that.- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
        case 37: //atras
            //if the cursor is at the beginning of the field
            if (event.target.selectionEnd == 0) {
                $(atras).focus();
            }
            break;
        ...
        case 39: //derecha
            //if the cursor is at the end of the field
            if (event.target.textLength-event.target.selectionStart == 0) {
                $(adelante).focus();
            }
            break;
```